# How to assert that element exists on the page using Node.js + Mocha + Selenium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I want to verify that element exists on the webpage. As I understood, selenium v3 removed "isElementPresent" functionality and there is some other ways to assert this. Can you give me an example of how to this without driver.isElementPresent, please?

For example, I have to verify that "password" field exists on the page - if true test passed, if false - test failed.

How can I do this using Node.js + Mocha + Selenium?
How can I assert, that element exists?

```
var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("password"));
assert.**???**(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the element by grabbing it with something like

```
var element = document.querySelector("input[type='password']");
```

Even better give the element an id and get it that way

```
var element = document.getElementById("password");
```

Then check for it

```
if(element) {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same question, and I came up with a solution.

For my approach, I used the following:

```
assert.doesNotThrow(() => { 
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("password"));
});
```

What is happening is that every time I attempt to find an element that doesn't exist, it raises an exception. If the element exists, then it doesn't throw an exception.

In my particular instance I used the following:

```
assert.doesNotThrow(() => { browser.getText('.alert.alert-danger') });
```

It appears to work well. If that changes, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Get the element by using the following command,

```
var element = document.getElementById("password");
```

Now check whether you got it or nut by asserting it,

```
assert.notEqual(element , null);
```